# How to limit multiple image selection from the gallery?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I have implemented adding multiple image selection from the gallery in my project. However, I want to limit the user so he/she can select only 3 images from the gallery.

I have implemented selecting multiple images from the gallery like this:

```
 `Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);`
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the count of `ClipData` when selecting multiple images from and gallery and if that count is greater than 3 you can notify the user about it.

You can do something like this after selecting images from gallery:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK || resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
              ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
              if(clipData.getItemCount() > 3){
                   //notify user here...
              }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE

You'll have to manually check the returned data to see if it's more than 10 items, and if so, show a Toast

Answer (score 0):

put this in your build.gradle(app)

```
 compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.5.0'
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.5.0'
```

and this in your activity

```
private void pickImage() {
    ImagePicker.create(UploadPhotosActivity.this)
            .showCamera(false)
            .limit(3)
            .imageTitle(getString(R.string.select_image))
            .folderTitle(getString(R.string.folder))
            .theme(R.style.ImagePickerTheme)
            .start(RC_CODE_PICKER);
} 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == RC_CODE_PICKER) {
            Log.d("===uploadPhoto", "gallery : " + data);
            imagesList = (ArrayList<Image>) ImagePicker.getImages(data);
            Intent intent = new Intent(UploadPhotosActivity.this, ImageCropperActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ImageCropperActivity.EXTRA_VIEW_PORT_RATIO, imagesList);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```